# Error: More than one instance of overload function "findCircumference" matches the argument list

Tags: c++

I cannot figure out what to do? I get the error just like in the title: `Error: More than one instance of overload function "findCircumference" matches the argument list.`

I am using scopes and functions for this assignment. If I can just figure out this error I can continue to work on other projects. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


// This program will demonstrate the scope rules.

// PLACE YOUR NAME HERE


const double PI = 3.14;
const double RATE = 0.25;

void findArea(float, float);
void findCircumference(float, float);


int main()

{

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    float radius = 12;

    cout <<" Main function outer block" << endl;
    cout <<" LIST THE IDENTIFIERS THAT are active here" << endl << endl;
    {
        float area;
        cout << "Main function first inner block" << endl;  
        cout << "LIST THE IDENTIFIERS THAT are active here" << endl << endl;

        findArea(radius, area);// Fill in the code to call findArea here

        cout << "The radius = " << radius << endl;
        cout << "The area = " << area << endl << endl;
    }

    {
        float radius = 10;
        float circumference;

        cout << "Main function second inner block" << endl;
        cout << "LIST THE IDENTIFIERS THAT are active here" << endl << endl;

        findCircumference(radius, circumference);

        cout << "The radius = " << radius << endl;
        cout << "The circumference = " << circumference << endl << endl;

    }

    cout << "Main function after all the calls" << endl;
    cout << "LIST THE IDENTIFIERS THAT are active here" << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}

//  *********************************************************************
//                           findArea
//   
//   task:     This function finds the area of a circle given its radius
//   data in:  radius of a circle
//   data out: answer (which alters the corresponding actual parameter)
//
//   ********************************************************************


void findArea(float rad, float answer)
{

    cout << "AREA FUNCTION" << endl << endl;
    cout << "LIST THE IDENTIFIERS THAT are active here"<< endl << endl;
    answer = (rad*PI)*(rad*PI);
    cout << answer <<endl;
    // FILL in the code, given that parameter rad contains the radius, that
    // will find the areato be stored in answer

}

//  ******************************************************************************
//                           findCircumference
//   
//   task:     This function finds the circumference of a circle given its radius
//   data in:  radius of a circle
//   data out: distance (which alters the corresponding actual parameter)
//
//   *****************************************************************************



void findCircumference(float length, float& distance)

{
    cout << "CIRCUMFERENCE FUNCTION" << endl << endl;
    cout << "LIST THE IDENTIFIERS THAT are active here" << endl << endl; 
    distance = (length*2)*PI;
        cout << distance << endl;

    // FILL in the code, given that parameter length contains the radius, 
    // that will find the circumference to be stored in distance

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the comments above the function definitions, it states that the function(s) must modify a parameter.

```
//   data out: answer (which alters the corresponding actual parameter)
```

You can do this by passing a parameter by reference i.e. appending a `&` character.

You also need to change the declaration and definition of the `findArea` function

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Your forward declaration is for a function that takes two `float` arguments by value

```
void findCircumference(float, float);
```

but your function signature is slightly different, taking one `float` by value and the second as a reference

```
void findCircumference(float, float&);
//                                 ^
```

You need to change them to match, presumably by correcting the forward declaration.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! This fixed any errors coming up, but when I run the program it closes instantly..    Here is what the Output's final comment says:  
The program '[7736] Project6_5.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Your code runs for me (with the correction from my answer).  Note that `findArea` should presumably also have its second arg as `float&` (the code currently displays an uninitialised value as the answer) but I can't see anything that'd obviously crash.

Comment: @user3063562 your `main` returns 0 so exiting with code 0 means that your program ran to completion.  If you run your exe from the command line rather than within an ide, you'll see its output (both good and bad).  Or you could add `string s;cin >> s;` to the end to force it to wait for user input before completing.

Comment: It opens the ommand prompt but instantly closes, I fixed the problem with the findArea aswell

Comment: Simonc thanks your advice helped the second problem too, just had to change the string to float and thank you too Andrew Douglas for your advice, you guys are quick!